# Vim adds and aligns new line and automatically inside quotes

Tags: vim, settings

Vim adds a new line when I am writing something inside quotes and the line hits the window width of the Vim.

For example:

```
export_data(...['official stmt url, issue',])
```

When writing something inside the quotes, this becomes:

```
export_data(...['official stmt url, issue
                 , new line aligned',])
```

I want to disable this feature. I guess this is caused by some settings in my vimrc file but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest fix to this is to disable textwidth:

```
:se textwidth=0 wrapmargin=0
```

to find the cause, do

```
:verbose set tw wm fo
```

which will show something like the following:

```
  textwidth=78
    Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/help.vim
  wrapmargin=0
  formatoptions=tcroql
    Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/help.vim
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a narrow value for `textwidth`. To disable it, set it to zero

```
set textwidth=0
```

See `:help textwidth` for full details.